# Evaluate sympy expression on one variable out of two

Tags: python, math, sympy, evaluation

I have a sympy expression with two variables

```
exp = x*y
```

I want to evaluate this function with y = 1 (to return a new expression new_exp = x)

I could only find the evalf function in the doc but it's not working (returns new_exp = x*y)

```
e.evalf(subs={y:1})
```

Any idea on this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

juste found out the sub function :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sympy-subs-method-2/

doing exactly the job